# Solving $|2^{x+1}-1|+|2^{x+1}+1|=2^{|x+1|}$. How do we work on absolute value of a power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm trying to figure out how do we work on absolute value of a power. Like in this question.

$$|2^{x+1}-1|+|2^{x+1}+1|=2^{|x+1|}$$

What am I supposed to to do here?

I need to solve for $x$, but I'm quite not sure of what should be my approach here?

A little help would be great.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: If everything else fails, you can still distinguish cases!

Comment: I tried applying the properties of mod and hence it's inside a modulus,so I reversed the signs of one of them. |

|2^(x+1)−1|+|-2^(x+1)-1|=2^|x+1|  and I used the property of |p|+|q|=|p+q|

Comment: Is $2^y$ ever negative?  When?  Is $2^y$ ever less than $1$?

Comment: "*and I used the property of $|p|+|q| = |p+q|$*"  That is only true when $p$ and $q$ are the same sign.  $|-2|+|5| =7 \neq |-2+5|=3$

Comment: 2^y isn't negative here,so I flipped the signs of both p and q inside modulus

Comment: That is what's going wrong everytime, I also tried to substitute a variable for 2^(x+1) but I'm getting stuck on the rhs

Comment: Since, it's an MCQ ,I can still do hit and trial but I need to know the correct process to solve it

Comment: Try taking cases: x>-1 and x<-1